# How to use justify-between vertically with Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a flex-col container I do not know the height of. I should be able to use justify-between in the container to separate two divs, on to the top and one to the bottom of the div, as its main axis is defined as vertical, and justify-between is used to 'justify items along the container’s main axis' according to the docs.

This code works horizontally:

```
<div class="w-screen h-screen bg-blue-200">
    <div class="flex justify-between">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if we change the second div to a 'flex-col' justify-between doesn't work along the vertical axis. Why is this?

```
<div class="w-screen h-screen bg-blue-200">
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-between">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Playground here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/41DdUFN3Fw

How can I achieve this, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will only work when the element's height increases:

```
<div class="w-screen h-screen bg-blue-200">
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-between" style="height:100vh">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `height:100vh` you can just add the class `h-full`.

Comment: I suppose it's because with a div being a block element, it naturally expands horizontally to fill its container. However, in flex-col mode, a div still 'behaves' horizontally ie. it still expands horizontally, not vertically, somewhat changing the expected behaviour of flex-col and justify-between